AWS Elemental Live - Querying API returns the GUI Interface
I'm attempting to query the AWS Elemental Live REST API using a Python script. I am using a generated header as described in the API documentation that allows me to authenticate and send the request, however, instead of receiving the expected XML response from the API endpoint, I'm getting the AWS Elemental Live GUI page pointing to that endpoint.
I also can see that I am logged in when inspecting the returned html response and that the response code is 200.
Example : http://<my-server-ip-address>/api/live_events/2  would point me to http://<my-server-ip-address>/live_events/2.
As i didn't configure the Instance myself, i only know that the AWS Elemental Live Server is running on CentOS, that httpd is being used and that the version is 2.25.4.730410. Can it be  linked to the Apache configuration? or is there any configuration for Elemental to enable/disable the API.

The issue was that I forgot to add
"Accept": "application/xml"
to the header when sending the request.
